# Show that any solution of second order differential equation has atmost a countable number of zeroes $?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Question :

Consider the second order differential equation $y''(t) + a(t) y'(t) + b(t) y(t) = 0$. Then any solution of the second order differential equation  has atmost a countable number of zeroes on $[a , b]$ .

What I have tried:

Let $S$ be the set of zeroes of $y(t)$. If $S$ is finite then there is nothing to prove.

Let $S$ be infinite . I can easily prove that every zero of $y(t)$ is isolated. Since $[a ,b]$ is closed and bounded and $S$ is an ordered set,  So we can find a minimum element of $S$ say $t_1$ so that for  $t_1 \in S $, there exists a $\delta_{t_1}$ such that in $( t_1 - \delta_{t_1} , t_1 + \delta_{t_1})$, $y(t)$ has no zeroes other than $t_1$

Let $ t_2$  be the minimum of $S-\{t_1\}$ of $y(t)$ . So   for  $t_2 \in S $, there exists a $\delta_{t_2}$ such that in $( t_2 - \delta_{t_2} , t_2 + \delta_{t_2})$, $y(t)$ has no zeroes other than $t_2$ and $( t_2 - \delta_{t_2} , t_2 + \delta_{t_2}) \cap( t_2 - \delta_{t_2} , t_2 + \delta_{t_2}) = \phi$. Similarly we can proceed.

Thus we can correspond for every $t \in S$ a rational number $ q_t $ which belongs to $( t - \delta , t + \delta)$ and since rational numbers are countable, so $S$ is countable.

Please check my soution, i f you think any correction is required, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any conditions (such as continuity) on the functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$?

Comment: I do not understand your argument. The zeros of $y$ form a closed set $S$, so certainly there is a minimum element of $S$. (But note that simply saying that $[a,b]$ is closed and bounded and That $S$ is an ordered set is not enough to justify this. The key is that $S$ is closed, and this is a consequence of the continuity of $y$.) Anyway, how did you conclude that $\delta_1$ exists?

Comment: $a(t) $ and $b(t)$ are continous, and the existence of $\delta_1$ is : any zero of $y(t)$ is isolated zero . so for any $t$, there exist a neighbourhood of $t$ in which no zero of $y(t)$ other than $t$. I am agree your point i should used the closedness of $S$.

Comment: Why are the zeros of $y$ isolated?

Comment: @ Andres : give me some time for typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can prove that $S$ is discrete, you are done, since any discrete set is countable. Proof: $S=\cup_{n=1}^\infty S\cap[-n,n]$, and $S\cap[-n,n]$ is finite.

Comment: @ Julian : I know about discrete topology but  not familiar of discrete set. please tell me about discrete set and $S$ is the subset of $[a,b]$

Comment: If $S\cap[a,b]$ were infinite, it would have a limit point, and then $S$ would not be discrete.

Comment: why is $S\cap[-n,n]$ is finite?

Comment: @vidyarthi Read the previous comment.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre now, why cant $S$ have a limit point?

Comment: Because then it would not be discrete.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre but, sir, this is cyclic reasoning. You are trying to prove that $S$ is discrete, isnt it?

Comment: No. I am not trying to prove that $S$ is discrete. I noticed that if it can be proven by whatever means that $S$ is discrete, then $S$ is countable. The fact that $S$ is discrete can be proved using differential equations techniques, which I assume the OP knew how to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am showing that every zero of non trivial solution $y(t)$ of differential equation $y''(t) +a(t)y(t) + b(t) y(t) = 0$ defined on $[a,b]$ is isolated

**Solution:**

Let $t_0$ be any zero of $y(t)$. if $y'(t_0) = 0$, and we have been given that $y(t_0) = 0$

Using the result that if $f(t)$ is the solution of the differential equation $a_n(t)y^{(n)}(t) + a_{n-1}(t) y^{(n-1)}(t) +......+a_1(t) y(t) = 0$ such that  $f(t_0) = f'(t_0) = .......= f^{(n-1)}(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0 \in [a,b]$. Then $f(t) = 0 $ for all $t \in [a,b]$, we get

$y(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ which is a contradiction

if $y'(t_0) > 0$, then there is a neighbourhood of $t_0$ says $(t_0 -\delta , t_0 + \delta)$  such that $y(t) > y(t_0)$ if $t \in (t_0 ,  t_0 + \delta)$ and $ y(t) < y(t_0)$ if $ t \in (t_0 - \delta , t_0)$   .

Thus $y(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in  (t_0 -\delta , t_0 + \delta)$ except $t_0$

Similarly we can prove the for $y'(t_0) < 0$
Thus $t_0$ is isolated zero of $y(t)$

Comment: It is very hard to read what you wrote, but here are some questions: First, why is it that if $y(t_0)=y'(t_0)=0$ then $y(t)=0$ for all $t$? (You quote a more general result, but then the question becomes why that more general result is true. It is here that you actually have to use that $y$ is a solution of the given differential equation, so this step seems to be the most important.) Second, it is true that $y$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $t_0$ if $y'(t_0)>0$, but do you see why?

Comment: @ Andres : I am not good in english , Sorry for this  and Firstly you have doubt why it is true if $y(t_o) = y'(t_0) =0 $, then $y(t) = 0$ for all t. you can see this result in S.l Ross . Second i have editting my problem . I think you will satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

You already proved that S is discrete. So that means for every x in S you can find a disk around x, say D(x,r) such that the intersection of D(x,r) and S-{x} is empty. Now since rationals are dense in the real line you can choose a rational number from each disk and hence you can index every disk by rational numbers. Since rationals are countable so is you disks. Which means S is at most countable.