# Discrete nature of the solution to differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This problem is taken partly from [Show that any solution of second order differential equation has atmost a countable number of zeroes $?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137841/show-that-any-solution-of-second-order-differential-equation-has-atmost-a-counta) 
There, in the accepted answer, it is shown that if the solution set is somehow proved to be discrete, the problem stands solved. But, how do you prove that $S$ is discrete?

Comment: There is an answer by user120386 which seems ok (if you assume $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ to be continuous). If you have $y(t_0)=0$ and $y'(t_0)=0$, then $y(x)\equiv 0$ solves $$\begin{cases} y''+a(t)y'+b(t)y=0\\ y(t_0)=0\\ y'(t_0)=0\end{cases}$$ hence the function $0$ is the actual solution by Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem. On the other hand, if $y'(t_0)\ne0$, there is a neighbourhood of $t_0$ where $y'(t)\ne 0$. In that neighbourhood $y$ must be injective by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli thanks, the answer given there was not, I hope, sufficiently rigourous due to lack of sufficient references to standard theorems. So, the theorems to be used are Cauchy-Lipschitz and Lagrange's theorems.